# How to open different new tabs depending on selected radio button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want the search button to be able to listen to the selected radio button, and open new tabs according to the selected radio button. Below is my code for the radio buttons and the search button:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/stylesheets/jurisdiction/indonesia/indonesia.css"> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/static/js/jurisdictions/indonesia/indonesia.js"></script>
    <title>MESA Indonesia</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="title">MESA Indonesia</p>
    </div>
    <p class="welcome">Welcome to the <span class="welcome">Indonesian</span> jurisdiction of MESA</p>
    <br><br>
    <div>
        <b style="color: black;">Corporate Records Research</b>
    </div>
    <form action="/indonesia/latest-corporate-records" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label class="pdfs" for="pdfs">Upload <span class="pdfs">PDFs</span> of an Indonesian company's latest corporate records here:</label>
        <input class="upload" type="file" name="pdfs" multiple>
        <button class="submit" type="submit" style="width: 240px; height: 34px; padding-top: 6px; padding-left: 12px;">
            <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 -1 20 20" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; background-color: transparent; justify-content: center; margin-left: 8px;">
                <path fill="white" d="M8.416,3.943l1.12-1.12v9.031c0,0.257,0.208,0.464,0.464,0.464c0.256,0,0.464-0.207,0.464-0.464V2.823l1.12,1.12c0.182,0.182,0.476,0.182,0.656,0c0.182-0.181,0.182-0.475,0-0.656l-1.744-1.745c-0.018-0.081-0.048-0.16-0.112-0.224C10.279,1.214,10.137,1.177,10,1.194c-0.137-0.017-0.279,0.02-0.384,0.125C9.551,1.384,9.518,1.465,9.499,1.548L7.76,3.288c-0.182,0.181-0.182,0.475,0,0.656C7.941,4.125,8.234,4.125,8.416,3.943z M15.569,6.286h-2.32v0.928h2.32c0.512,0,0.928,0.416,0.928,0.928v8.817c0,0.513-0.416,0.929-0.928,0.929H4.432c-0.513,0-0.928-0.416-0.928-0.929V8.142c0-0.513,0.416-0.928,0.928-0.928h2.32V6.286h-2.32c-1.025,0-1.856,0.831-1.856,1.856v8.817c0,1.025,0.832,1.856,1.856,1.856h11.138c1.024,0,1.855-0.831,1.855-1.856V8.142C17.425,7.117,16.594,6.286,15.569,6.286z"></path>
            </svg>
            Upload Corporate Records
        </button>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    </form>
    <div class="subject-name-search">
        <form id="subject-search-form" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
            <div id="person-search-provinces">
                <div class="states-dropdown-list">
                    <b style="color: black;">Litigation Research</b>
                    <ul class="states-dropdown" style="list-style: none; margin-left: -40px; column-count: 3; -webkit-column-count: 3; -moz-column-count: 3; width: 900px;">
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="supremecourt" checked>Supreme Court of Indonesia</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="jakarta">Special Capital Region of Jakarta</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="aceh" disabled>Aceh</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="bali">Bali</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="bangkabelitung">Bangka Belitung Islands</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="banten">Banten</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="bengkulu">Bengkulu</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="centraljava" disabled>Central Java</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="centralkalimantan">Central Kalimantan</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="centralpapua">Central Papua</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="centralsulawesi">Central Sulawesi</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="eastjava" disabled>East Java</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="eastkalimantan">East Kalimantan</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="eastnusatenggara" disabled>East Nusa Tenggara</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="gorontalo">Gorontalo</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="highlandpapua">Highland Papua</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="jambi" disabled>Jambi</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="lampung" disabled>Lampung</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="maluku">Maluku</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="northkalimantan">North Kalimantan</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="northmaluku">North Maluku</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="northsulawesi">North Sulawesi</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="northsumatra" disabled>North Sumatra</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="papua">Papua</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="riau" disabled>Riau</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="riauislands">Riau Islands</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="southeastsulawesi">Southeast Sulawesi</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="southkalimantan" disabled>South Kalimantan</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="southpapua">South Papua</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="southsulawesi" disabled>South Sulawesi</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="southsumatra">South Sumatra</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="southwestpapua">Southwest Papua</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="westjava" disabled>West Java</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="westkalimantan" disabled>West Kalimantan</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="westnusatenggara">West Nusa Tenggara</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="westpapua">West Papua</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="westsulawesi">West Sulawesi</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="westsumatra" disabled>West Sumatra</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="radio" name="company-state" class="state" value="yogyakarta">Special Region of Yogyakarta</label></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p style="font-size: small;">Note: Disabled provinces have more than 20 court IDs. <span style="font-weight: bold; color: darkgreen;">Please check them separately.</span></p>
                    <br><br>
                    <button class="search" id="search" style="background-color: darkgreen; color: white; border: none; border-radius: 4px; height: 34px; width: 200px; cursor: pointer; " onclick="matchingCourtNames()">
                        <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 -3 20 20" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin-left: 2px; background-color: transparent; padding-top: 6px;">
                            <path fill="white" d="M18.109,17.776l-3.082-3.081c-0.059-0.059-0.135-0.077-0.211-0.087c1.373-1.38,2.221-3.28,2.221-5.379c0-4.212-3.414-7.626-7.625-7.626c-4.212,0-7.626,3.414-7.626,7.626s3.414,7.627,7.626,7.627c1.918,0,3.665-0.713,5.004-1.882c0.006,0.085,0.033,0.17,0.098,0.234l3.082,3.081c0.143,0.142,0.371,0.142,0.514,0C18.25,18.148,18.25,17.918,18.109,17.776zM9.412,16.13c-3.811,0-6.9-3.089-6.9-6.9c0-3.81,3.089-6.899,6.9-6.899c3.811,0,6.901,3.09,6.901,6.899C16.312,13.041,13.223,16.13,9.412,16.13z"></path>
                        </svg>
                        Search Court Databases
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="company-search-states" style="display: none;">
                <div class="states-dropdown-list">
                    <b style="color: darkgreen;">Corporate Records Research</b>
                    <ul class="states-dropdown">
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="aceh">Aceh</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="bali">Bali</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="bangkabelitung">Bangka Belitung Islands</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="banten">Banten</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="bengkulu">Bengkulu</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="centraljava">Central Java</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="centralkalimantan">Central Kalimantan</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="centralpapua">Central Papua</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="centralsulawesi">Central Sulawesi</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="eastjava">East Java</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="eastkalimantan">East Kalimantan</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="eastnusatenggara">East Nusa Tenggara</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="gorontalo">Gorontalo</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="highlandpapua">Highland Papua</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="jakarta" checked>Special Capital Region of Jakarta</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="jambi">Jambi</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="lampung">Lampung</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="maluku">Maluku</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="northkalimantan">North Kalimantan</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="northmaluku">North Maluku</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="northsulawesi">North Sulawesi</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="northsumatra">North Sumatra</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="papua">Papua</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="riau">Riau</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="riauislands">Riau Islands</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="southeastsulawesi">Southeast Sulawesi</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="southkalimantan">South Kalimantan</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="southpapua">South Papua</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="southsulawesi">South Sulawesi</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="southsumatra">South Sumatra</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="southwestpapua">Southwest Papua</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="westjava">West Java</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="westkalimantan">West Kalimantan</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="westnusatenggara">West Nusa Tenggara</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="westpapua">West Papua</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="westsulawesi">West Sulawesi</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="westsumatra">West Sumatra</label></li>
                        <li><label><input onclick="enforceMaxNumberOfSelectedStates(event)" type="checkbox" name="company-state" class="state" value="yogyakarta">Special Region of Yogyakarta</label></li>
                    </ul>
                    <button style="background-color: white;" onclick="searchCorporateRecords()">
                        <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; background-color: transparent;">
                            <path fill="white" d="M18.109,17.776l-3.082-3.081c-0.059-0.059-0.135-0.077-0.211-0.087c1.373-1.38,2.221-3.28,2.221-5.379c0-4.212-3.414-7.626-7.625-7.626c-4.212,0-7.626,3.414-7.626,7.626s3.414,7.627,7.626,7.627c1.918,0,3.665-0.713,5.004-1.882c0.006,0.085,0.033,0.17,0.098,0.234l3.082,3.081c0.143,0.142,0.371,0.142,0.514,0C18.25,18.148,18.25,17.918,18.109,17.776zM9.412,16.13c-3.811,0-6.9-3.089-6.9-6.9c0-3.81,3.089-6.899,6.9-6.899c3.811,0,6.901,3.09,6.901,6.899C16.312,13.041,13.223,16.13,9.412,16.13z"></path>
                        </svg>
                        Search Court Databases
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my code for the functions that I create separately:

```
function selectedCourtNames(){
    var matches = [];
    for(i in document.querySelector('input[name="subject-type"]:checked')){
        if(i.value == 'riauislands'){
            matches.push(i);
            matchingCourtNames.forEach(url => window.open(url));
        }
    }
    return matches
}

function matchingCourtNames(){
    //KEPULAUAN RIAU
    var urlsforriauislands = [
       "http://www.sipp.pn-bandaaceh.go.id/",
       "http://sipp.pn-sabang.go.id/",
       "http://sipp.pn-tanjungpinangkota.go.id/",
       "http://sipp.ptun-tanjungpinang.go.id/",
       "http://sipp.pa-tarempa.go.id/",
       "http://sipp.pa-natuna.go.id/",
       "http://sipp.pa-batam.go.id/",
       "http://sipp.pa-tanjungpinang.go.id/",
       "http://sipp.pa-dabosingkep.go.id/",
       "http://sipp.pa-tbkarimun.go.id/",
   ]
   for(let i = 0; i < urlsforriauislands.length; i++){
       window.open(urlsforriauislands[i], "_blank", windowFeatures='popup=true, height=700, width=700');
   }
   window.close();

   let matches = selectedCourtNames();

   if(matches === true){
    window.open(urlsforriauislands)
   } else if(matches == false) {
    null
   }
}
```

The code now opens multiple tabs, but it doesn't respond accordingly to the selected radio button. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: `window.open(urlsforriauislands[i], "_blank", windowFeatures='popup=true, height=700, width=700');` opens all the tabs. You need to get a better understanding of what functions do

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't reflect changes made by selecting different radio buttons

Comment: Too many issues in your code. The logic is broken almost everywhere. Try to explain to yourself what expression row in your code does and returns. That might help.

Comment: Just one of them: `selectedCourtNames()` returns an array, but `matches` is used as boolean

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252842/html-js

Comment: Given your html: `document.querySelector('input[name="subject-type"]).length == 0`